# Android unable to start activity android.view.inflate exception. Application crashing on `setContentView()`

Tags: java, android

I have started with android programming. These application start up crashes are driving me nuts. Currently I have one Android Application and one Android Library Project in eclipse. I am geting following error in logcat

**Logcat**

```
01-22 06:00:33.167: E/AndroidRuntime(25666): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.camerafilters/com.example.camerafilters.CameraMainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView
01-22 06:00:33.167: E/AndroidRuntime(25666):    at com.example.camerafilters.CameraMainActivity.onCreate(CameraMainActivity.java:44)`
```

the library is `TwoWayView`. Here is my `activity_main.xml` file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<com.example.camerafilters.CameraGLSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/CameraGLSurfaceView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="8"/>

<org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ShaderList"
    style="@style/TwoWayView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    tools:context=".CameraMainActivity"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my `onCreate()` function

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //_cameraGLView = new CameraGLSurfaceView(this, null);
    // Create a GLSurfaceView instance and set it
    // as the ContentView for this Activity. 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    _cameraGLView = (CameraGLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.CameraGLSurfaceView);
    _renderer = _cameraGLView.getRenderer();

    _renderer.setPreviewDimensions(_cameraGLView.getWidth(), _cameraGLView.getHeight());

    // now setup list view of shader
    _setupShaderListView();
}
```

let me know if any more code is required. Application crashes in `setContentView()` function. I have one more project in same workspace which uses same configuration. That project also uses one `GLSurfaceView` and `TwoWayView` List that project is working fine.

here is stacktrace

```
CameraFilters [Android Application] 
DalvikVM[localhost:8617]    
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
        <VM does not provide monitor information>   
        ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2308    
        ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2362 
        ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 168    
        ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1329  
        ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
        Looper.loop() line: 177 
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5493    
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 525  
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1225 
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 1041    
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)    
    Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running) 
    Thread [<11> GLThread 22597] (Running)
```

**Update** 
So i did some more debugging and found out that both projects are in different drives. Does that make any difference ? The project which is running successfully is in same drive in which `TwoWayView` is. While this project is in eclipse workspace and different drive then two way view.

**Update 2** 
I moved library to same directory but still no luck. Even now the one that was working works :(. Some more investigation and comaparison between these two projects is giving some pointers. Though I have done same configuration but I can see this `TwoWayView` in `Project Properties->Android` Library section where as in this project i can't. When i removed this library from there former project also started crashing.

Comment: post org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView

Comment: *Here is my layout.xml file* -- shouldn't it be `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: haan yes sorry ! its `activity_main.xml` only

Comment: As @blackbelt said, you should post `TwoWayView` class anyway. It looks like there might be a problem there, maybe your other projects just don't trigger the problem.

Comment: @Joffrey 
TwoWayView is way too big to post. Here is link https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Indeed ^^

Comment: @Joffrey i have updated my question with new findings. See you can help with it !

Comment: I think this is a library reference problem. Make sure TwoWayView is a library project in your eclipse, and reference it as library from your other project. I'm not very familiar with the process, but this should help: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Comment: I am doing exactly as you said.. There is a plethora of similar questions on SO but none helped :(

Answer (score -1):

Change to this:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<com.example.camerafilters.CameraGLSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/CameraGLSurfaceView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="8"/>

<org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView

    android:id="@+id/ShaderList"
    style="@style/TwoWayView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    tools:context=".CameraMainActivity"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

and post full stack trace.